# Is Postfix a SMTP server?

Tags: postfix, smtp

Last couple of weeks I was trying to setup a hMailServer on windows, but there were some problems so I decided to give a unix-based solution a try.

I am running a roundcube webmail and Ubuntu with postfix and dovecot. Inbox work fine with IMAP but I am not able to send any emails via SMTP.

I always get

```
Error SMTP (554): Unable to add recipient "vojtech.basta@XXX.cz" (5.7.1 <vojtech.basta@XXX.cz>: Relay access denied)
```

So what I understand from the postfix settings it only accepts emails for specified list of domains (that is for the domains it lists the emails for). But I need to direct Roundcube to some SMTP server that can deliver email to all domains.

Am I using a wrong SW or is it just misconfigured?

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mydestination = dynapos.cz,sweetparadise.cz, ubuntu.mshome.net, localhost.mshome.net, localhost
myhostname = mail2.sweetparadise.cz
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = no
virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Comment: Configure your clients to use smtp authentication

Comment: You're using exactly the right software.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow your Postfix to accept relay mails from Windows Server(s) (`1.2.3.4` & `1.2.3.5` in this case).

- Add the following content in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/check_client_access, reject_unauth_destination
```

- Setup `/etc/postfix/check_client_access` with the following

```
1.2.3.4         OK
1.2.3.5         OK
```

- Run `postmap hash:/etc/postfix/check_client_access` to generate hash map for Postfix.
- Run `postfix reload` to reload configuration.

Then try it again.